# Which element is throwing the "ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating an automtated testing script in selenium using webdriverJS.(*node.js approach*)

I have some menus and submenus.

I am trying to click a collapsible button, which opens a menubar. Under each menu, there are some submenus.

[image]

I have an array like

```
minorSize = (
0 => ,
1 => ,
2 => 7,
3 => 3,
4 => 5,
5 => 8,
6 => 4,
7 => 3)
```

Where

```
menu <li[2]> has 7 submenu,
menu <li[3]> has 3 submenu,
menu <li[4]> has 5 submenu,
menu <li[5]> has 8 submenu,
menu <li[6]> has 4 submenu,
menu <li[7]> has 3 submenu
```

Following is the function which is a recursive one to visit through each menu and submenu.

```
function clickMenu(iMajor, majorLinkLast,iMinor)
{
    driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'navbar-minimalize minimalize-styl-2')]"))));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'navbar-minimalize minimalize-styl-2')]")).click().then((function(iMajor,majorLinkLast,iMinor){
        driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(By.id('side-menu'))));
        (function(iMajor,majorLinkLast,iMinor)
        {
            majorMenuXPath = "//ul[contains(@id, 'side-menu')]/li["+iMajor+"]/a";
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(majorMenuXPath)).click().then((function(iMajor,majorLinkLast,iMinor){
                minorMenuXPath = "//ul[contains(@id, 'side-menu')]/li["+iMajor+"]/ul/li["+iMinor+"]/a";
                driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(By.xpath(minorMenuXPath))));
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(minorMenuXPath)).click().then((function(iMajor,majorLinkLast,iMinor) 
                {
                    console.log(iMajor+" "+ minorSize[iMajor]+" "+iMinor);
                    iMinor = parseInt(parseInt(iMinor) + 1)
                    if(iMinor <= minorSize[iMajor])
                    {
                        /*driver.getTitle().then(function(title) 
                        { 
                                console.log(title); 
                        });*/
                        clickMenu(iMajor,majorLinkLast,iMinor);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(iMajor < majorLinkLast)
                        {
                            iMajor = parseInt(parseInt(iMajor) + 1)
                            clickMenu(iMajor,majorLinkLast,1);
                        }   
                    }
                })(iMajor,majorLinkLast,iMinor));
            })(iMajor,majorLinkLast,iMinor));
        })(iMajor,majorLinkLast,iMinor);
    })(iMajor,majorLinkLast,iMinor));
}
```

The function is called from the test suit in this fashion.

```
majorLinkLast = parseInt(majorLinkSize + 1);
var iMajor = 2;
clickMenu(iMajor,majorLinkLast,1);
```

After clicking three times(three submenus) for a menu, the script throws a 
"*ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible*" exception.

**Is there any way by which I can know which particular element did cause the exception? Some log functions or methods?**

Here's the exception report:

```
    ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
    (Session info: chrome=45.0.2454.101)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.19.346078   
    (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114
    1),platform=Windows NT 5.1 SP3 x86)
     at Array.forEach (native)
    From: Task: TrackRevenue Click Menu Test View page by clicking menu
```

Comment: You could add a try-catch block around the line that throws the exception, and print the clicked element's details.

Comment: @skandigraun, I don't know which one throws the exception. Its a recursive function. Also either menu, or any submenu may throw the exception. The collapsible button may also throw the exception. I want to know, is their any logging functions which displays the element causing the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Does a submenu link closes the submenu after been clicked?

If it does so, you must trigger a click on the parent menu link, (the one that opens the submenu) always before clicking on a new submenu link.

Comment: I am actually doing the same as you have stated brother. But still I am getting the error

Comment: Add some delay between clicks to let the DOM catch up on the UI changes. In C#, I use `Thread.Sleep(200)`. In JavaScript, you might need to use Timeouts `SetTimeout()`, which might be a bit annoying. But test it to see if it solves the problem.